# Netbeans: How do I break on a NullPointerException?

Tags: netbeans, debugging, breakpoints

When debugging a java program in netbeans, I want the debugger to stop on the line that causes a NullPointerException so I can examine the variables there.  I believe I have to use a condition on the breakpoint set at that line, but what is the syntax of the condition?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Go to debug > New Breakpoint (alternatively CTRL+SHIFT+F8). Change the breakpoint type to Exception in the top right hand drop down menu. Type `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the Exception class field. Choose whether to break on caught, uncaught or both.

Debug your code and watch the glorious auto breakpoint when the Exception is thrown.

Comment: I did that and it's simply not stopping, like the breakpoint is not even there. Using netbeans 7.0.1. and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` Help.

Comment: Note that at the bottom of the New Breakpoint Dialog there is a field to stop the current thread or all application threads, also you can make "All threads" the default value, in my case that was the most useful.